Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli
I'm encountering an issue while trying to run cordova emulate android in my project. The error message I'm seeing is:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli

This error occurs during the build process and seems related to apkanalyzer. I've checked my Android SDK installation and environment variables (ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT), which are correctly set.
Additionally, I've updated my build tools (build-tools;32.0.0) and ensured my Java JDK version (JDK 11) is compatible.
Steps I've tried:

Verifying SDK tools installation.
Updating environment variables.
Adding android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33 to gradle.properties.
Ensuring JDK compatibility.

Despite these steps, the issue persists. How can I resolve this ClassNotFoundException with com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli?

This question is similar to: 'apkanalyzer' is not recognized as an internal or external command. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
